# How can i send a string from my Swing application to javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, swing, applet

i am trying to send a string from my swing application to javascript, i tried using JSObject sendIt = JSObject.getWindow(this); but i get an the following error

"because method getWindow in class netscape.javascript.JSObject cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.applet.Applet
  found: work
  reason: actual argument work cannot be converted to java.applet.Applet by method invocation conversion"

parts of my code below

```
public class work extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private void uploadButtonMouseClicked (java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        // System.out.println("its here");
        theHash = (String) sender.uploadFunction(filesArray[i], uuid);
        System.out.println("Uploading " + filesArray[i] + "\n");
        JSObject sendIt = JSObject.getWindow(this); //error       
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Fix the formatting if your code.  2) How would a JFrame object have a javascript context with which to work?  That's what the error is telling you; you're not in an Applet environment.  What are you trying to do, and why?  You're talking about two different pieces; Java is typically back-end/server side, with Javascript being front-end/client side.

Comment: i m creating a drag and drop applicaion to upload files through sftp, all files dropped unto the jtext area are uploaded and stored on the server in a folder with a random string name for each upload, i would like to pass this string name to a javascript function after each upload

Comment: Have a look at [Java-to-Javascript Communication](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html) document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only call `JSObject.getWindow(this)` from within your Applet object, so 'this' should be a reference to an Applet object.

By the way, you should enable this in your applet tag:

```
<APPLET code="..." width="..." height="..." MAYSCRIPT>
```